# AS3 removing local enterFrame listener

Tags: actionscript-3, listener, flash-cs5, flvplayback

(I don't know why the question doesn't show the "hello")

Anyway, hello all,

I have this code:

```
myVideo1.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.METADATA_RECEIVED, timeListener);

function timeListener(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void
{ 
var totalSeconds = String(eventObject.info.duration);
durationTime = String(Math.floor(totalSeconds));

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTime2);//<---LISTENER

var timeFull = durationTime;

function updateTime2(event:Event):void
{
    var elapsedSeconds = String(Math.floor(myVideo1.playheadTime));
    var runTime:String = (elapsedSeconds);
    var timeGone = Math.floor((eventObject.info.duration) - (myVideo1.playheadTime));
    var timeRem = Math.floor(timeGone / 60);
    var secGone = String(timeGone / 60 - timeRem);
    // etc...
}
}
```

This piece of code gets the remaining "seconds" of the video.

How can I remove the `enterFrame` listener? Where in the code?

It's printing the `Error #1009` when jumping to the next frame of the main timeline.

Anyway, the movie is running "normally", so the question is for learning purposes.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Where is your script that takes you to the next frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTime2);
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the answer before. Yes, I must use a remover. I was using the remover outside the function, and it wasn't working. That's why the question.

Comment: So was the answer correct? If it was, I would gladly appreciate it if you mark it as correct. :)